# Java TokenBucket RateLimiter not generating Tokens

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, rate-limiting

I have implemented token bucket rate limiter as below with max 10 requests allowed in 1 second per user. Initially token bucket will be filled with 10 tokens per user if all of the 10 tokens are used by the same user in 1 second of time user is rate limited as expected however if the user tries to make the request again after 1 second delay am seeing the user is rate limited again because `refillBucket()` is not refilling the tokens with 1 second delay as configured in the `Thread` can someone please help me fixing this bug?

Answer (score 1):

In `TokenBucketRateLimiterImpl` your `sleep` should be:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(rateLimitWindow);
```

And not:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(rateLimitWindow * 1000);
```

Otherwise your token rate limiter will refill after 1000 seconds, instead of 1 second.